# How to replace the default appearance of a button with an Image? [JavaFx using Scene Builder]

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

What I want my button to look like is just an image which you can click on. But when I try to put an image(which have transparent background) on it, the appearance of the button is still there

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<fx:define>
   <Image fx:id="btnImage" url="images/image.png" />
</fx:define>
```

and

```
<graphic>
        <ImageView image="$btnImage" />
</graphic>
```

on the .fxml file

and also using scene builder's ImageView

[image]

But as I've said earlier, this is how the button looks like:

[image]

as you can see the gray background of the button is still there, I want it to look like this:

[image]

Basically an image that you can click. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the background color of the button to be transparent. You can do it like this: `button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");`

Comment: I totally forgot that 'transparent' is valid when setting background color. And to properly answer my question, this can be found under Properties > Style (under JavaFX CSS section).

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this easily using code instead using Scene Builder?

```
package testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML public Button myButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)  {

        File imageFile = new File("images/image.png");
        Image image = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString());
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        myButton.setText("");
        myButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        myButton.setGraphic(imageView);


        // Add an event click to the button
        myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("You clicked: " + ((Button)event.getSource()).getId());
            }                
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm depending on scene builder too much.

Comment: @itskenleton I the past I was too. But now, I use more code than Scene Builder, because it's more flexible.